# in Angular 11, How to update the content of a dynamically rendered component with ngComponentOutlet?

Tags: angular

I have an app with Angular 11. In the app, I have a menu created from an array of objects that have the following structure:

```
{
  icon: CUSTOMER_ORDER_PROPERTIES.icon,
  iconColor: CUSTOMER_ORDER_PROPERTIES.color,
  label: 'Search Customer Order',
  routeBase: 'search-customer-order',
  component: C1Component,
  callback: (
    router: Router,
    routeBase: string,
    tabsService: TabsService,
    label: string
  ) => {
    router.navigateByUrl(routeBase);
    tabsService.emitTabClick(label);
  },
}
```

My goal is that when clicking on each item generated by this array, the associated component specified in its component property should be dynamically loaded.

I handle the click event using this method:

```
handleItemCallback(item: NeosMenuItem) {
  if (item.callback) return;
  item.callback(this.router, item.routeBase, this.tabsService, item. Label);
}
```

When the click event occurs, the callback navigates using router.navigateByUrl to the URL associated with that object. For example, clicking on the first object navigates to search-customer-order.

In the page-routing.module, I have set up routes to dynamically capture that route:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: appRoutes.HOME,
    component: PagesComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: appRoutes.HOME,
        component: WelcomeComponent,
      },
      {
        path: appRoutes.NOT_FOUND,
        component: NotFoundComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
      {
        path: ':dynamicRoute', // Dynamic route here
        component: DynamicComponentLoaderComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

The DynamicComponentLoaderComponent dynamically captures the dynamic URL, uses it to get the clicked object, obtains the associated component, and renders it in its template using ngComponentOutlet.

```
export class DynamicComponentLoaderComponent implements OnInit {
  loadedComponent: any | null = null;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const dynamicRoute = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('dynamicRoute'); // obtiene ruta dinamica
    console.log(
      ' DynamicComponentLoaderComponent ~ ngOnInit ~ dynamicRoute:',
      dynamicRoute
    );
    const menuItem = searchMenu.find((item) => item.routeBase === dynamicRoute); // get clicked item
    if (menuItem && menuItem.component) {
      console.log('Loading component:', menuItem.component.name); // log the loaded component

      this.loadedComponent = menuItem.component; // assign the loaded component to the component to be rendered
    } else {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/not-found');
    }
  }
}

<ng-container *ngIf="loadedComponent">
  <ng-container [ngComponentOutlet]="loadedComponent"></ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

The problem is that the DynamicComponentLoaderComponent only renders once (with the correct component) when clicking on an item, but it never renders again. The log I have in ngOnInit only fires the first time I click on a menu item, but not afterward.

I've tried using changeDetection.push but haven't had success. Where could the bug be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the **Angular [ComponentFactoryResolver](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactoryResolver)**.
What you need to do is the following:

```js
export class DynamicComponentLoaderComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private factory: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private ref: ViewContainerRef
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const dynamicRoute = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('dynamicRoute');
    console.log(
      ' DynamicComponentLoaderComponent ~ ngOnInit ~ dynamicRoute:',
      dynamicRoute
    );
    const menuItem = searchMenu.find((item) => item.routeBase === dynamicRoute); 
    if (menuItem && menuItem.component) {
      console.log('Loading component:', menuItem.component.name);

      // Set up factory for new component
      const componentFactory = this.factory.resolveComponentFactory(menuItem.component);
      // Clear current displayed component/view of this component
      this.ref.clear();
      // Instantiate component with factory
      const componentRef = this.ref.createComponent<any>(componentFactory);
      // Additionally you can acces the instance of the new component and fill it with data
      //componentRef.instance.PROPERTY = DATA;
    } else {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/not-found');
    }
  }
}
```

You can leave the components view empty or add a placeholder if nothing is loaded/not found.